# split string that includes semicolons in Hive

Tags: hive

how can I achieve splitting a string field delimited by semicolons in hive?

```
select split(f1,";")[0] from table;
```

Comment: you can try to escape ; with \\; it worked for me.

Comment: I tried that. It does not work (hive 0.10).

Answer (score 7):

You can write this way

`select split(f1,'\073')[0] from table;`

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to re-iterate that this is indeed a Hue bug, but only in the Hortonworks version. The latest Cloudera version of the Hue runs this fine.

Answer (score 1):

The below command will work:

### input table

```
 1;Neethu KV
  2;Ram KV
```

query 1:

`select split(name,"\\;")[0],school from table_test`, where name refers to your column name to be split.

### output

```
1 KV
2 KV
```

Query 2 :

`select split(name,"\\;")[1],school from table_test`, where name refers to your column name to be split.

### output

```
Neethu KV
Ram KV
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured that this is a bug in Hue, \; works fine from command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using '\03B' instead of semicolon . It worked for me . Have a try .

Answer (score 0):

The split function expects a regular expression.

For special characters, it should suffice to escape them, e.g. '\;'

https://linuxandryan.wordpress.com/2014/03/05/hive-split-on-special-characters-escape-in-split/